# Python Selenium - How to click in a button in a div, based on a text of another DIV

Tags: python, selenium

With Python Selenium, I want to click on a button "Add..." based on another div.

I cannot use the `xpath following::div` as spotted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186328/python-selenium-how-to-click-a-button-next-to-specific-text) because they are in different divs.

Basically, look for the first div text to contain some text and based on it, I want to click on button "Add..." on fourth div. This on a serie of Divs, as you can see on screenshot.

[image: screenshoot]

On example/code below, I want to find "Template 1" <- xpath `//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[24]/div[1]/div/h3/text()[1]`

and base on that

I want to click on button 'Add...' <- xpath `//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[24]/div[4]/div/table/thead/tr/th[3]/button`

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 50px;" class="">
   <div>
      <div>
         <h3>
            <!-- react-text: 1148 -->Template 1<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 1149 -->&nbsp;<!-- /react-text -->
         </h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group btn-table-action pull-right" style="vertical-align: top; top: -32px;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="color: rgb(51, 122, 183);"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="color: rgb(217, 83, 79);"></i></button></div>
   <div class="detail-pane" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); border-radius: 4px; font-size: 90%; padding: 4px 20px; margin-bottom: 14px;">
      <div>
         <h5></h5>
         <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <span>
               <dt style="font-weight: normal;">Key</dt>
               <dd style="font-weight: normal;">template-1-key</dd>
            </span>
         </dl>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <h5 style="color: rgb(95, 94, 94); margin-top: 27px;">Templates</h5>
      <div class="detail-pane" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); border-radius: 4px; font-size: 90%; padding: 4px 20px; margin-bottom: 14px;">
         <table class="table table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed;">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th>Language</th>
                  <th>Asset Path</th>
                  <th>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-xs" style="margin-left: 6px;">
                        <span>
                           <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o">&nbsp;</i><!-- react-text: 1174 -->Add...<!-- /react-text -->
                        </span>
                     </button>
                  </th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">No entries found so far...</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok can you say few things? like the first div class is different or same with other divs? is there any specific id for the add buttons or all add buttons are smae?

Comment: There is several div class before - as you can see in the added xpath. The list of div which interest here start at `//*[@id="app"]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]`. The button are all the same, no id.

Comment: *based on a text of another DIV*... Which `div`? What is the text?

Comment: I added an example. The text change.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below xpath and let me know if it is working for you

```
.//div/h3[text()[normalize-space() = 'Template 1']]/../../following-sibling::div/div//table//tr/th/button[@type='button']
```

Explanation :

```
.//div/h3[text()[normalize-space() = 'Template 1']]   // To locate element with "Template 1" text

/../..     // to navigate the parent node for template 1 node

following-sibling::div/div//table//tr/th/button[@type='button']  // Locate the button node which is sibling node  of parent div of Template 1 text
```